# how to do relationships and usersession in the framework?

Tags: php, frameworks

I do own framework and lean call at this tutorial and several other

http://anantgarg.com/2009/03/13/write-your-own-php-mvc-framework-part-1/

I have two problems in connection with the framework,

1 As the easiest way to do relationships?

2 How to do sessions and login and registrations, whether it was best to SHA512 encryption? Is it enough to do it on functions or in some other way?

current framework repository is located here
https://bitbucket.org/zixxus/myframework/overview

Answer (score 0):

Why not refer to some existing frameworks to see how they do things?
Why reinvent the wheel when you can use some of the code they do if their license allows it or if they are happy for you to.

Here is laravel - http://laravel.com/

Currently laravel uses (AES encryption via the mcrypt PHP extension) http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security#encryption